# Why is all my checkbox working except one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sql, checkbox

I'm trying to build a WHERE clausure using checkbox, I got 4 checkbox working and 1 not working, I don't get why that one isn't working since the code works for all 4...

Here's my code

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="cc" class="cc" value="0" /><label for="c1"><span></span></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="c2" name="cc" class="cc" value="1" /><label for="c2"><span></span></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="c3" name="cc" class="cc" value="2"  /><label for="c3"><span></span></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="c4" name="ll" class="ll" value="1"  /><label for="c4"><span></span></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="c5" name="ll" calss="ll" value="0"  /><label for="c5"><span></span></label>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.cc').change(function() {
   if($(this).is(":checked")) {
      alert($(this).val());
      query = '?filter=type=' + $(this).val();
      filter();
      return;
   }
   query = '';
   filter();
});

    $('.ll').change(function() {
   if($(this).is(":checked")) {
      alert($(this).val());
      query = '?filter=local=' + $(this).val();
      filter();
      return;
   }
   query = '';
   filter();
});


});
```

Somebody please help me... all my checkbox are working using this method except the checkbox c5... that checkbox looks like never trigged... I'm tried to put an alert() when I check but the alert never work, so looks like the c5 never trigger... I'm trying to pass arguments to a WHERE sql query when a checkbox is changed...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

You got a typo! The fifth checkbox has a `calss`-attribute instead of a `class`.

Comment: Omg dude didn't notice that lol. Thanks for pointing it!! what a dumb mystake that I made... Thanks bro.

Answer (score 0):

There is no **calss** your code change it to **class**

Replace that;

```
<input type="checkbox" id="c5" name="ll" calss="ll" value="0"  /><label for="c5"><span>        </span> </label>
```

With that and try;

```
<input type="checkbox" id="c5" name="ll" class="ll" value="0"  /><label for="c5"><span>        </span> </label>
```

Comment: Lars Ebert has already given the answer, that too 3 mins earlier.

Comment: Better save than sorry ;)